# Get all(one to many) records belongs to a user as an array from mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table as below

```
user    category
1          157
1          158
2          158
2          159
3          157
```

Required output using PHP is

```
[
    1 => [157,158],
    2 => [158,159],
    3 => [157]
]
```

One solution could be get all result from `mysql` & then run a `foreach` on it like this

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $finalResult[$row['user']][] = $row['category'];
}
```

But is there any other optimal way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT()` function for this.

Here's the reference:

- [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

So your query should be like this:

```
SELECT user, GROUP_CONCAT(category SEPARATOR ',') AS categories FROM your_table GROUP BY user;
```

Output:

```
+------+------------+
| user | categories |
---------------------
|   1  |  157,158   |
---------------------
|   2  |  158,159   |
---------------------
|   3  |    157     |
+-------------------+
```

**Edited:**

```
// suppose $conn is your connection handler

$finalResult= array();
$query = "SELECT user, GROUP_CONCAT(category SEPARATOR ',') AS categories FROM your_table GROUP BY user";

if ($result = $conn->query($query)) {

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $finalResult[$row['user']] = explode(",", $row['categories']);
    }

}
```

Comment: `group_concat` result into string not an array, I want array as an result

Comment: @KuldeepDangi If *array* is your requirement, then your solution is optimal in my opinion.

Comment: @KuldeepDangi I have proposed an alternative way in the **edited** section of my answer. This way you'll get the desired output.